# How to find common words and print them using python command?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to cross check names from two word documents and then print the common names in the same program. How do I do so? Do I use regex or simply use the in function?

Answer (score 15):

Once you have the text out of the Word documents, it's really quite easy:

```python
document_1_text = 'This is document one'
document_2_text = 'This is document two'

document_1_words = document_1_text.split()
document_2_words = document_2_text.split()

common = set(document_1_words).intersection( set(document_2_words) )
unique = set(document_1_words).symmetric_difference( set(document_2_words) )
```

If you're not sure how to get the text out of Word docs:

```python
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def get_text_from_doc(filename):
    word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
    word.Visible = False
    wdoc = word.Documents.Open(filename)
    if wdoc:
        return wdoc.Content.Text.strip()
```

Answer (score 8):

```
str1 = "Hello world its a demo"

str2 = "Hello world"

str1_words = set(str1.split())

str2_words = set(str2.split())

common = str1_words & str2_words
```

output:

```
common = {'Hello', 'world'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the words from one document, then go through the words of the second document checking to see if each word was in the previous document. So, if I had two strings instead of documents, I could do this:

```
a = "Hello world this is a string"
b = "Hello world not like the one before"
```

Store the words in the string:

```
d = {}
for word in a.split():
  d[word] = true
for word in b.split():
  if d[word]:
    print(word)
```

Comment: Better use a `set` intersection, they even have an operator for intersections.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "Hello world its a demo"
str2 = "Hello world"

for ch in str1.split():
  for ch2 in str2.split(): 
      if ch == ch2:
          print ch
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came on this thread and didn't see this method, so I just wanted to add that you
can do this:

```
from collections import Counter

foo = "This is a string"
bar = "This string isn't like the one before"

baz = Counter(foo.split(" ")) + Counter(bar.split(" "))
baz = sorted(baz, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

*Baz* is now a dict that looks like this

```
Counter({'This': 2, 'string': 2, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, "isn't": 1, 'like': 1, 'the': 1, 'one': 1, 'before': 1})
```

Now you can see that the two strings have *"This"* and *"string"* in common

You could also convert all the strings (*foo* and *bar*) to lowercase using **.lower()** before you use **Counter()** on them so that everything is counted equally